# VS Code: enable inline spell checker, but disable spell check in the "Problems" panel

Tags: visual-studio-code, spell-checking, vscode-extensions

I use the code spell checker for VS Code. I would like to disable the spell checker warnings/errors in the "PROBLEMS" panel (standard keyboard binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) where "more serious" problems show up.

Often there are so many spell checker errors that I have to scroll down to the "real" problems :-)

[image]

Comment: Yeah these Intellisense drives me crazy. Too much distracting, specially if you are fixing "real" problem.

Comment: You can filter problems using regex.

Answer (score 144):

See [issues: don't show in Problems pane](https://github.com/Jason-Rev/vscode-spell-checker/issues/186).  It is suggested to try:

```json
"cSpell.diagnosticLevel": "Hint",
```

in your settings.json.  This will remove them from the problems pane.  However, in your files these "hints" are now indicated by three small dots under the beginning of the misspell and are not all that apparent.  You can modify them with the colorCustomization:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  // will change the color of three dots to red
  "editorHint.foreground": "#ff0000",

  // will underline the entire word with dots in your chosen color
  "editorHint.border": "#00ff66"
}
```

This will give you both sets of hint dots, you can hide the built-in three dots by making them transparent:

```json
"editorHint.foreground": "#f000",
```

Comment: Dear mark. Thanks :-) We must wait until the issue is fixed or fix it ourself :-)

Comment: For me in 1.44.1 `editorHint.border` does not underline the whole word, it just makes 4 dots instead of 3. And they are slightly bigger dots. Probably visible enough for me: https://imgur.com/a/FZuvEjq

Comment: For anyone interested in a better solution to this, please check the VSCode issue and upvote it: https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/issues/186

Comment: Already very cool! But:
1. The `editorHint` option is not recognized anymore as a valid setting.
2. Not the full word is underlined, only the dots.

Comment: @DrumM The `editorHint` `colorCustomizations` are still recognized.  They must be put into the `workbench.colorCustomizations` object within your settings.

Comment: is it possible to make cspell aware of the names of the installed python packages? I keep having errors for packages names that aren't plain english

Answer (score 19):

Just Toggle Spell option in command pallete (View-Command Pallete)
[image: Disable Spell Checking]

Comment: The questions seeks to disable spelling errors in "Problems Panel", while keeping the underlines. Not disabling it all together.

Comment: Nice catch Zhaolin, but most of us want to disable it altogether.

Comment: @Bryan then just uninstall it

Answer (score 16):

- Go to setting *(Ctrl+,)*
- type `cSpell.diagnosticLevel` in a search box
- change the option to **Hint**

Answer (score 3):

I've just unchecked `C Spell: Enabled` in **Settings** and all the *Spelling related warnings* has been disappeared.

[image: Imge ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2):

write "!word" in the terminal > problem tab > search bar. it's a regular expression syntax. "!word" means all errors without an error name word. it will exclude all word-related errors.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFqJe.png)

Comment: This is a simple and creative solution that got buried since it was submitted so late.

Answer (score 1):

HIDE:

Enable Dictionary
Commands (use F1 or View -> Command Palette...):

Enable Spanish Spell Checker Dictionary
Enable Spanish Spell Checker Dictionary in Workspace
Disable Dictionary
Commands (use F1 or View -> Command Palette...):

Disable Spanish Spell Checker Dictionary
Disable Spanish Spell Checker Dictionary in Workspace

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go settings.json file.
Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and type `cSpell.enabled`. `cSpell.enabled` should be `true`, change it to `false`:

[image]

Comment: > This setting cannot be applied because it is not registered as language override setting.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on word and click show spell check configuration info from menu .A spell checker tab will appear then click on file info and deselect spell checker enabled for file type(in my case it was typescript).

Comment: What's the point? Just disable the extension instead.

Answer (score 0):

It stopped working for me in `.mdx` files.

I explicitly enabled all file types by adding a `*` to the `C Spell: Enable Filetypes` in the Settings page in VS Code and it is working again!

[image]

Comment: You can also use [Enable Spell Checking Document Language](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/issues/657#issuecomment-755459018)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want have any specific file or word you can write it in `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "cSpell.diagnosticLevel": "Hint",
    "cSpell.words": [
        "crazyword"
    ],
    "cSpell.ignorePaths" : [
        ".golangci.yml",
        ".vscode/settings.json"
    ], 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only annoyed by the info level minimap highlight, and would tolerate othrewise manually filter out info level problems, I suggest the following and keep the wave underscore info level tips inline

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "minimap.infoHighlight": "#00000000", // minimap hide info level highlight
},
```

Answer (score -1):

if your problem is this then follow the below step to solve

go to your setting  vs shortcut ctrl+,
inside setting panel search cspell

when you search csepll  you get the option

unchecked this cspell and your problem is solved

Answer (score -1):

First go to the setting at the bottom left side of VS code window,

[Setting Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsRrD.png)

Search for "spell" in the search bar,

[Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktCnR.png)

Now toggle the Enable/Disable Spell Checker option and disable it.

[Toggle the Enable option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPIJ4.png)